# The 'Electorate' Badge explantation doesn't make sense...

Tags: discussion, badges

Is it just me (and it *may* indeed be just me!) or does the explanation text for the 'Electorate' badge make absolutely no sense?

"*Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions*"

Just pokin' around (looking for things to edit, naturally!) and that popped out at me...

Answer (score 5):

There are two ambiguous terms there,

> Voted on 600 **questions** and 25% or more of **total votes** are on questions

The first `questions` refers to questions and their answers; so in practice, voting for this answer would count, and voting for the question would count, but voting for both the question and the answer would only count once.

This then makes the `total votes` clearer, as this badge is going to count all things reported as up and down votes on your profile (comment up votes are not, at present, nor do they count) - you need 25% of all those votes to actually be on the question and not the answer (actually, voting for both question and an answer will count for the first total, and move your weighting toward 50%)

Answer (score 4):

The question you should be asking yourself is, "600 is 25% of what?"

- You voted on 600 questions.
- 25% or more of your total votes are on questions.

If both of the above are true, you will get the badge.

Comment: OK, fair enough, it *is* me. :-)

Comment: No, I think it's confusing too.

Comment: @reid it has to fit in a very limited space. We can't write war and peace in a badge description :)

Comment: Is the limitation based on a certain number of characters?

Comment: @Jay Turns out the interface to supplying badge descriptions is Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so based on @Jeff's answer above I was wondering, wouldn't:

"Voted at least 2400 times, and 25% or more of total votes were on questions"

say the same thing, but potentially say it in a clearer way? Just trying to see if I can find a less awkward way to express the badges intention...

Comment: No, because, theoretically, all 2,400 of those votes *could* be on a single question and its answers, which doesn't satisfy the 600 different questions portion.

Comment: For instance, [there is a user](http://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1457/alfred-myers) that has achieved the badge, and currently has only made 610 votes -- in fact [all the users with the badge](http://photo.stackexchange.com/badges/44/electorate) have less than 1900 votes (at time of writing)

Comment: @rowland correct that user is voting on ALL questions, then, by definition. If you cast 600 votes on questions *and nothing else* e.g. no answers, you'll get it.